# python xml fromstring can not decode gbk encoding?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I encoding xml with "gbk":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, fromstring, XML, XMLParser

root = Element('root')
child = SubElement(root, "child")
child.text = u"中文"

result = tostring(root, encoding="gbk")
print(result)
print(result.decode("gbk"))
```

this will generate result like this:

```
b"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='gbk'?>\n<root><child>\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4</child></root>"
```

So, I am trying to parse xml like this, I do it like this:

```
tree = XML(result.decode("gbk"))
print(tree[0].text)
tree = XML(result.decode("gbk"), parser=XMLParser(encoding="gbk"))
print(tree[0].text)
tree = XML(result.decode("gbk"), parser=XMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))
print(tree[0].text)
```

I find that all of them work in `python 3.6`, but none of them works in `python 2.7`, the error in `python 2.7` is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 50-51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, I have two question:

1. why both `XMLParser(encoding="gbk")` `XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")` return same result in `python3.6`
2. how to make the xml parser works fine in `python2.7`?(I don't think `result.decode('gbk').encode('utf8').replace('GBK', 'utf-8')` is a good idea.)

Comment: Set the encoding on your script?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I do not understand

Comment: Set this as the first line of your script `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think it has nothing to do with this matter, I just didn't copy these lines, but I will append it.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, XML
>>> root = Element("root")
>>> child = SubElement(root, "child")
>>> child.text = u"中文"
>>> result = tostring(root, encoding="utf-8")  # Return str in Py2, Return bytes in Py3
>>> result
'<root><child>\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87</child></root>'
>>> print type(result)
<type 'str'>  # The type str in Py2 is the type bytes in Py3
>>> print result.deocde("utf-8")
<root><child>中文</child></root>
>>> tree = XML(result)
>>> print tree[0].text
中文
```

For the second question, the above code works in Python 2.7.

UPDATE

I guess your purpose is construct XML from gbk encoded string. You can use `lxml` in Python2 or use Python3 directly.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.Element("root")
>>> child = etree.SubElement(root, "child")
>>> child.text = u"中文"
>>> result = etree.tostring(root, encoding="gbk")
>>> result
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='gbk'?>\n<root><child>\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4</child></root>"
>>> tree = etree.XML(result)
>>> tree[0].text
u'\u4e2d\u6587'
```

Comment: In my situation，I have to use gbk encode xml, you have change my question